# How to stop select box to use select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-select2

i have many dropdowns in my page.

for dropdowns i am using [select2 plugin](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2).

i don't want to use select2 plugin for some of the dropdowns.

is there any way to do so?

i have searched on google and also have gone through their documentation but i didn't get anything related this.

this is my select box code ..

```
    <div class="cust-input">
     <select name="management[]">
          <option value="0">Select Management</option>
          <option value="Chairman">Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chairman">Vice Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chancellor">Vice Chancellor</option>
          <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
          <option value="Registrar">Registrar</option>
          <option value="Dean">Dean</option>
          <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: pls provide ur js code also

Comment: Add a js class to the select element you DO want the select2 to style and call it on them: ```$(".js-select2").select2();```

Comment: here for this dropdown i am not calling select2() method but then also its getting style and functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that using specific *class* instead of common `select` tag element.

use:

```
$(".useSelect2").select2(); //either your desired name of your class or unique ID
```

instead of

```
 $("select").select2(); // if you used this method, select2 will applied to all dropdowns.
```

Example:

```
     <select name="management[]" class="useSelect2">
          <option value="0">Select Management</option>
          <option value="Chairman">Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chairman">Vice Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chancellor">Vice Chancellor</option>
          <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
          <option value="Registrar">Registrar</option>
          <option value="Dean">Dean</option>
          <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
```

Javascript:

```
        $(".useSelect2").select2();
```

Other dropdowns:

```
     <select name="management[]" class="dontuseSelect2">
          <option value="0">Select Management</option>
          <option value="Chairman">Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chairman">Vice Chairman</option>
          <option value="Vice Chancellor">Vice Chancellor</option>
          <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
          <option value="Registrar">Registrar</option>
          <option value="Dean">Dean</option>
          <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: here for this dropdown i am not calling select2() method but then also its getting style and functionality.

Comment: my js file is too big.. it contains 3500 lines.. but i have checked and have searched this $("select").select2(); but i didn't find it and also i have tried by disabling .js files from that particular page but then also its taking select2() for select box..

Answer (score 1):

Put a class on the `select` elements you want to use select2 with, and then use that class to instantiate the plugin. Something like this:

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

```html
<div class="cust-input">
    <select name="management[]" class="select2">
        <option value="0">Select Management</option>
        <option value="Chairman">Chairman</option>
        <option value="Vice Chairman">Vice Chairman</option>
        <option value="Vice Chancellor">Vice Chancellor</option>
        <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
        <option value="Registrar">Registrar</option>
        <option value="Dean">Dean</option>
        <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <!-- this select will not be styled -->
    <select>
        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: here for this dropdown i am not calling select2() method but then also its getting style and functionality.

Comment: Search in your code for `.select2(`. It will be being set somewhere.